# adicion valor errado al hacer sentencia SQL

Tags: php, sql

Buenos días estimados amigos,

Tengo la siguiente situación con el siguiente código, al hacer seguimiento, todos los datos son obtenidos satisfactoriamente pero no funciona correctamente, no hace el update o el insert debido a que se adiciona una variable al $query y no tengo idea de donde la esta jalando, el resultado es el siguiente: `INSERT INTO nombre_producto (nombre) VALUES('AAA')1`.  El ultimo uno que imprime no se de donde lo saca, y por supuesto genera siempre error.  adiciono el codigo javascript y php, lo raro es porque adicionar este numero al final de la sentencia.

```
function guardarDatosGenerales(nombre, id) {
    let datos = $(`#input${id}`).val();
    debugger;

    if (editar) {
        id_registro = $(`#txt${id_tbl}`).val();
        data = { datos: datos, id_registro: id_registro, tabla: nombre, operacion: 3 };
    } else
        data = { datos: datos, tabla: nombre, operacion: 3 };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/c_propiedades-generales.php",
        data: data,

        success: function (r) {
            debugger;
            if (r == 1) {
                alertify.set("notifier", "position", "top-right"); alertify.success("Operacion exitosa.");
                refreshTable(id);
            } else {
                alertify.set("notifier", "position", "top-right"); alertify.error("Error");
            }
        }
    });
}

<?php
   require_once('../../../conexion.php');
   require_once('./crud.php');


    $tabla = $_POST['tabla']; 
    $dato =  $_POST['datos'];

        if (isset($_POST['id_registro'])) {
            $id_registro = $_POST['id_registro'];
            $query = "UPDATE $tabla SET nombre = '$dato' WHERE id = '$id_registro'";

            echo $query;
        } else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO $tabla (nombre) VALUES('$dato')";
            echo $query;
        }

      ejecutarQuery($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Y datos donde existe? Por qué yo veo dato en singularb

Comment: Revisa los dos archivos del `require_once`

Comment: Muchas gracias, el valor lo tenia en el requiere_once @A.Cedano

Comment: Bien. Deberías usar consultas preparadas. Cualquier hacker puede atacar tu sistema al dejar pasar variables a ejecución directamente. Por SQL se puede acceder no sólo a la BD, sino incluso al sistema de archivos.